# Android WiFi Direct Data Communication Example

Tags: android, tcp, wifi-direct

Can anyone suggest a good example for get an idea about creating TCP server and client with android WiFi direct to transfer data. (Actually transfering of strings not files)

Actually I did one, but I cannot get the IP of server from client side.

Answer (score 0):

If server and client are connected to the same wifi network, then please try use the `192.168.1.40` IP in the client to send data to server.

For example in client:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.40", port);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.example.androidclient;

 MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
   dstAddress = addr;
   dstPort = port;
  }

try {
    socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = 
                  new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int bytesRead;
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
   }
```

Comment: I did this. Only I have the issue with getting the server IP. The parameter you passed "addr". How can I get the IP of server side.